# Displaying questions for a gameshow-like quiz

Tags: linux, game-development, presentation, quiz

I am looking for a software solution to host a quiz in the style of a game show, pub quiz, or similar. It mainly needs to display questions for the participants and audience in an appealing manner (using a screen or projector).

Desired features, roughly in order of relevance. I expect that not all criteria are met:

- Can display a single-choice question with up to four options.
- Uses the entire display.
- Displays countdown for each question (how long participants have to select a solution).
- Can highlight the solution afterwards.
- Controllable by key presses or similar.
- Allows to easily manage the order and style of questions.
- No WYSIWYG clickfest, but rather like LaTeX.
- Facilitates collaboration of quiz creators, e.g., collecting questions, reviewing each others questions, etc.
- Can display open questions, i.e., without answer options.
- Can include images to go along with certain questions.
- Can play sound or video for certain questions.
- Can display an explanation of the solution after a question.

Not needed:

- Managing participants (the audience does not directly interact with the software).
- Logging in answers.
- Counting points.
- Automatic progression (except for the timer).
- Complete ready-to-use solution. I can do some light programming or similar myself.

Environmental constraints:

- Runs on Linux.
- Free.

#### My thoughts so far

- LaTeX allows to do almost everything, but displaying a timer is difficult.
- Classical presentation software (e.g., LibreOffice Impress) can probably do everything, but is a clickfest.
- I could probably program something using Python and/or Jupyter, but that requires some time investment and it may be difficult to economically use the entire display.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by LaTeX here and how that would be ever any more comfortable for defining questions than WYSIWYG. Also, "runs on Linux"? For who, the host, the client, both? Or is the client irrelevant and the questions will be just written down or something rather than registered online?

Comment: If that's the case then Impress with help of some quiz templates is likely way way easier than anything else. But "logging in answers" and "counting points" suggest otherwise, so you should definitely include how you imagine the interaction to happen. And then freemium quiz websites are likely your best bet.

Comment: @Destroy666: I edited my question to clarify some things: There is not host and client, just displaying. Participants do not interact directly with the software at all. As for WYSIWYG vs. LaTeX-like, that’s a matter of taste and application. For me and my particular application, I clearly prefer a powerful tool with a concave learning curve that can be meta-programmed if necessary.